# What is the correct jquery selector to get all select dropdowns with a certain class name?

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, selector

i want to loop through all dropdown selects with a certain class name and add an item to it and i am just struggling with the correct selector

---

**EDIT:**  I must be doing something wrong as most of the upvoted accepted answer dont seem to work so i think there must be some quirk in my code.  I have pasted both the HTML and the jquery code below.  let me know if this makes sense.

---

**HTML:**

```
<select onfocus="this.enteredText='';" onkeydown="return handleKey();" onkeyup="event.cancelbubble=true;return false;" onkeypress = "return selectItem();"  class="componentSelect"  id="components0" name="applicationUpdater.dependencies[0].componentName" >
<option value= 5 >Client</option>
<option value= 79 >Server</option>
</select>

 <select onfocus="this.enteredText='';" onkeydown="return handleKey();" onkeyup="event.cancelbubble=true;return false;" onkeypress = "return selectItem();"  class="componentSelect"  id="components1" name="applicationUpdater.dependencies[0].componentName" >
<option value= 5 >Client</option>
<option value= 79 >Server</option>
</select>
```

etc . . .

**jquery code:**

```
    $('select.componentSelect').each(function() {
        var select = $(this);
        $(select).children('option').each(function() {
            if ($(this).text() == currentComponentName) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your new question, you can use the following line to remove all `<option>`s containing a `currentComponentName`:

```
$('select.componentSelect option:contains("' + currentComponentName + '")').remove();
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/osemu/)

Answer (score 15):

**You should use the [.class selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/class#class).**

```
// select every <select> element with classname "yourclassname"
$('select.yourclassname').each(function() {
    // $(this) now refers to one specific <select> element
    // we append an option to it, like you asked for
    $(this).append(
        $('<option value="foo">Bar</option>');
    );
});
```

For more information about how to properly select elements with jQuery, take a look at http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors.

Answer (score 7):

Give this a shot:

```
$('select.className').each(function() {
   var currentSelect = $(this);
   // ... do your thing ;-)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`.className`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) selector, like this:

```
$('select.className')
```

This selector combines the [element](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) selector (matching all `<select>` elements) with the className selector (matching all elements that contain the `className` class) to find all `<select>` elements with that class.

Answer (score 1):

Your posted jQuery code works for me, as long as I define `currentComponentName` to be one of the options of your select.  Aron Rotteveel's answer is very close, but the append part is a bit off, try this:

```
$('select.componentSelect').each(function() { 
    $(this).append('<option value="foo">Bar</option>'); 
});
```